# SQuish AUT crashes after trigger a modal from help menu

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, adobe, squish

i am trying to automate a Desktop application that uses Qt framework for its UI.
I go to the Help menu in the main menu and click on and option called "Welcome screen". this welcome screen is like a pop-up that appears on top of the application.
When i try to trigger this popup by click on Welcome screen, the AUT crashes

what's causing this and how can i resolve this issue?

Issue persists every time, it is not a one-time thing